# Have any free flash media services for testing my project?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flash-media-server, fms3

I am using FMS. But I use this only in locally. Are there any free flash media server services to test my project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Red5](http://red5.org/) Open source flash media server written in java.